# Undefined local variable in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax, simple-form

Edit:
It turns out, this was really an issue of syntax when using `render` for partials. It should be `render partial:`

---

I am following this blog post guide to implement the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem.
http://twocentstudios.com/blog/2012/11/15/simple-ajax-comments-with-rails/

I have a `character` model with the following comment form partial in the `show.html.haml` view.

This line is giving me an undefined local variable or method for 'comment'

**app/views/characters/show.html.haml**

```
  ...
  = render 'comments/form', :locals => { comment => @new_comment }
  ...
```

The hash inside the locals hash seemed off to me, so i changed the `comment` local variable to `:comment`. This worked fine, but I don't believe that is I am supposed to do.

When I do this, the form partial that is rendered also uses a `comment` local variable.

**app/views/comments/_form.html.haml**

```
.comment-form
  = simple_form_for comment, :url => comment_path, :remote => true do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    = f.input :body, :input_html => { :rows => "3" }, :label => false
    = f.input :commentable_type, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_type
    = f.input :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_id
    = f.error :base
    = f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => "Submitting…"
```

Notice that the object passed into the `simple_form_for` method is also a local variable. This raised an error too, and i turned it into a symbol as well. Next, the `comment.commentable_type` raised an error, naturally, because `comment` was not defined. I cannot turn this into a hash because it is having a method call on it, right?

Whatever the answer is to the question is, it seems like I am going about this the wrong way. I shouldn't be turning things into symbols, when the problem is really that it isn't defined. Where should I define it? Where and how should I define it? I tried simply doing `comment` in the comments controller,

I am using rails 4.0.0, using simple form, and haml. Could it be a bad syntax for simple form?

---

EDIT: it was a second line rendering the comment partial that was raising the error. (everything being named comment was making it hard to tell where it was coming from.

```
  = render 'comments/form', comment: @new_comment
  = render 'comments/a_comment', collection: @comments, as: :comment


-# partial for a single comment.
%div.comment{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}" }
  %hr
  = link_to "×", comment_path(comment), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this comment?", :disable_with => "×", :class => 'close'
  %h4
    = comment.user.username
    %small= comment.updated_at
  %p= comment.body
  %h4
```

Comment: You forgot to add : in front of comment. Try with this: `= render 'comments/form', :locals => { :comment => @new_comment }`

Comment: Hi thank you for commenting. As explained in the OP, i've tried this. What do you suppose I should do about the subsequent issues that arise? I can't do `simple_form_for comment`. If I do `simple_form_for :comment`, then the `comment.commentable_type` won't work. turning this into a sybmol wont work either.

Comment: `:locals => { :comment => @new_comment }` is definitely the right syntax, but has `@new_comment` been defined?  If not then in the form the `comment` local variable will be set to `nil`.

Comment: The symbol thing can be little confusing: the reason is that you're setting a variable **name** and a variable **value**.  The symbol is for the name, and it points to the value to assign to that variable.

Comment: Right, it's a hash, so it needs to be a symbol or a string, not a local variable. Is it OK to have a local variable as the first argument of the form method in the form? If so, how does the local variable `comment` get recognized in the form partial? Does using the matching symbol name enable the matching local variable?

Comment: Indeed, `@new_comment` is not being set. In the charcters controller -> show action, the line is `@new_comment = Comment.build_from(@character, current_user, "")`, as the github readme guide, and the guide i linked in the OP said, but it is not working apparently. (current_user is from devise gem)

https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading

Comment: "the reason is that you're setting a variable name and a variable value." This means the symbol in this method results in the creation of a local variable of the matching "string" (i.e. comment) - am i understanding you correctly? I may have missed what you meant precisely. If so, I mistakenly asked a question you already answered.

Comment: You could do `render @comments` and see what partial it is expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def show
  @character = Character.find(params[:id])
  @new_comment = @character.comments.build
end
```

Assuming there is a `has_many` relation between `character` and `comment`.

In your view:

```
render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { new_comment: @new_comment }
```

or

```
render 'comments/form', new_comment: @new_comment
```

In your partial:

```
= simple_form_for new_comment, remote: true do |f|
```